# Calling a URL from a stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Just wondering if its possible to call a URL from a stored procedure (eventually adding that procedure to a sql job)  As the webpage refreshes my database, it would be excellent if I could automate this process.

Edit:

I want to be able to request a webpage from a store procedure. On the page load of the desired webpage there is a function that refreshes my database.  I want it to refresh my database at 4 am every day. In order for me not to manually go onto the site at 4am (still sleeping) I need something else to do it for me. I thought sql jobs would be excellent, as I can set the time, and the job up. I don't know PowerShell all that well, and wanted to know if I could request a URL, or visit a url using a stored procedure or any other way.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail please whyt you want to do? This kind of request starts alarm bells usually...

Comment: okay edited it with more detail. Not trying to rise alarms, just lazy and I want something else to request the webpage, though I can see where you are coming from though

Comment: this seems like a much-too complicated way to do something rather simple, which is "execute code at 4am every day". you can do that with a scheduled task (in Windows), or a Windows service etc.

Comment: my computer won't be on (or hooked up to the net as its a laptop), and I don't think I can set a scheduled task on the test server

Comment: Here's another way to call a URL from a SP (using sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1', etc.). But as other methods, it will require to lower the security of the SQL Server:
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=111356

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with Task Scheduler (part of Windows). Just create a scheduled task that opens Internet Explorer and browses to the page:

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://yoursite.com/yourpage.aspx"
```

Or for 64-bit Windows:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://yoursite.com/yourpage.aspx"
```

Alternatively, create a job using SQL Server Agent, and create a single step of type "Operating System (CmdExec)" with the above command.

Comment: but my computer won't be on (or hooked up to the net), and I don't think I can set a scheduled task on the test server

Comment: @Spooks: Schedule on the database server? or use a command task in SQL Server Agent with the same command?

Comment: It's worth looking into. I use a shared hosting provider and they let me schedule tasks, so even if you're using shared hosting you might be able to.

Comment: I don't think I have access to the Task Scheduler on the database server. I can access the command task in the SQL server Agent though...

Answer (score 7):

@newurl is url you want to hit
@response is response you received

```
EXEC Sp_oacreate  'MSXML2.XMLHTTP',@obj OUT;
EXEC Sp_oamethod @obj,'open',NULL,'get',@newurl,'false'
EXEC Sp_oamethod @obj,'send'
EXEC Sp_oamethod @obj,'responseText',@response OUTPUT   
EXEC Sp_oadestroy @obj
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure MS SQL doesn't allow you to do that directly.. obvious security issues. However, I think you can get around it by using xp_cmdshell to execute a vbscript file and in that file, create an xmlhttp request to a site.

xp_cmdshell command:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'c:\<file>.vbs',no_output
```

VBScript:

```
call main()
sub main()
    Dim xmlHTTP, url
    Set xmlHTTP = WScript.CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
    url = "<url>"
    xmlHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    xmlHTTP.Send  ""
end sub
```

**EDIT**

In response to a comment on how to do this asynchronously.

xp_cmdshell command:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'c:\caller.vbs',no_output
```

VBScript for caller:

```
call main()
sub main()
    Dim scmd
    Set scmd = "c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe //nologo c:\<originalVBS>.vbs"
    createobject("wscript.shell").run scmd,0,false
end sub
```

Comment: anyway of doing that asynchronously?
This way the exec command keeps running util all the URL processing is done

Comment: @Diego: I updated the code to reflect how you could mimic an asynchronous approach.