# Send a HTTP Request Using SQL Server Agent Jobs

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to create a SQL SERVER Job which automatically send a HTTP Request at specified intervals?

Comment: Similar Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798538/calling-a-url-from-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the SQL Server CLR to create the function you need.

[Introduction to SQL Server CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

You can also enable sql server cmd shell and run something like curl to send the request. This is nothing I would recommend though.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO

-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE
GO

-- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO

-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.

RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Download [Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)

Comment: Is there is any alternative? Is there is no other option in sql server to send a http request?

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

You can execute a vbs script `EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'c:\<file>.vbs',no_output` and inside that script you can use code like, [found this on SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4798669/507184)

```
call main()
sub main()
    Dim xmlHTTP, url
    Set xmlHTTP = WScript.CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
    url = "<url>"
    xmlHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    xmlHTTP.Send  ""
end sub
```

---

You can use [`CmdExec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190264.aspx) and execute a command like

> "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://your-url-here/"

Comment: That's a terrible soution actually!

Comment: @VamsiKrishna, I agree with Asken. Why I need to open a browser for sending a single request?

Comment: I know the various ways to issue a HTTP request but I need to use SQL SERVER.

Comment: Check [Make a http request from SQL Server](http://networkprogramming.wordpress.com/2010/09/01/make-a-http-request-from-sql-server/) it might be of some help