# Convert a file URL to file byte in using a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, data-migration

My database has a table of person, and on that table there is a column named `PersonImageUrl` (which is hosted in a public container in azure). I have an upcoming migration to a new database. The new column in the new database table requires `VARBINARY(max)`. I want to create a stored procedure to convert the contents of `PersonImageUrl` (file where the URL points to) into a byte array so that it would meet the requirements of my migration. Is this possible?

Comment: What is the expected content of that byte array? The URL or the bytes of the file that the URL points to?

Comment: You can try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798538/calling-a-url-from-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server to get the image, and pass the result as a byte array to your stored procedure.

Comment: @DaleK I have tried heavy research but unfortunately I did not found any answer.

Comment: Seems like you have the image URL. So you need to download the image, convert to byte array and save to new database. This can't be done with a stored procedure.

Comment: Why doesn't the new table _also_ just point to the URL? Storing the bytes in the database is troublesome for a bunch of reasons, most importantly: SQL Server disk space is _way_ more expensive (and usually throughput-sensitive) than basic file systems designed exactly for, well, storing and serving files.

Comment: Probably a hugely bad idea to do this from a stored procedure, TSQL is not a generalized scripting language. Instead use a proper scripting language such as Powershell, Python or C# to download, then push it into SQL Server.

Comment: I don't understand. "byte array" is not a SQL Server concept, it's a programming concept. It would hepl to exaplain in more detail - what is the piece of client code that you are using that requires "byte array"? Because VARCHAR can be considered a byte array. It's a bunch of bytes that can be accessed by position.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid to clarify, the data type is VARBINARY(max)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure SQL Database (and SQL Server 2017+) has a built-in integration to Azure BLOB storage, and for a public container you don't even need a credential,
Eg:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE BlobStore
WITH 
(
   TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
   LOCATION = 'https://MyStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net'
);


SELECT BulkColumn Image 
FROM OPENROWSET
(
   BULK 'MyPublicContainer/someimage.jpg',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'BlobStore',
   SINGLE_BLOB
) AS blob;
```

[Examples of bulk access to data in Azure Blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Hi  @David Browne, My friend has a related question about this. Posted here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69743468/how-to-add-a-dynamic-url-inside-an-openrow-set

Comment: Hi @David Browne, Have you tried using this with files inside a folder in azure container? 
could not be opened. Operating system error code 32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Comment: A Blob container doesn’t have folders.  Using ‘/‘ to emulate folder structure is just a convention.

Comment: Hi @David Browne, I think my main issue here is that when I open the URL via browser it works but in the stored procedure it will throw this error, could not be opened. Operating system error code 32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process